# Errors in c++ compiling

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

Okay so I'm trying to compile a school project on a linux server, but it's throwing errors at me. The compiler I'm using is g++, & for the record this program worked fine on my Mac before i uploaded it to this server. Basically, I just don't know how to read this error message, so I don't know what to fix, where to fix, or what code you guys need to see. If someone could please tell me what to post on here so you guys can infer further you would be awesome... Oh and my project is due at 11:00 tonight :D Haha anyways, below is the command I typed and then the message it spat out at me.

```
g++ Song.cpp Song.h test_tsuPod.cpp tsuPod.h tsuPod.cpp
```

And now the error.... get ready for some gibberish

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ios:39,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test_tsuPod.cpp:9:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ios_base.h: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/ios_base.h:790: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:47: error: within this context
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:87: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/streambuf: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/streambuf:770: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:78: error: within this context
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd: In copy constructor ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/iosfwd:87: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf(const std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here 
In file included from test_tsuPod.cpp:10:
tsuPod.h: In copy constructor ‘tsuPod::tsuPod(const tsuPod&)’:
tsuPod.h:23: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)’ first required here 
test_tsuPod.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_tsuPod.cpp:23: note: synthesized method ‘tsuPod::tsuPod(const tsuPod&)’ first required here
```

If you can save me, I will forever be in your debt!! Thank you!

Here is the code from tsuPod.h

```
#ifndef __project5__tsuPod__
#define __project5__tsuPod__

#include <iostream>

#endif /* defined(__project5__tsuPod__) */

#include "Song.h"
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;


class tsuPod {
  private:
  int MAX_SONGS;
  int MAX_MEM;
  int num_songs;
  int memory;
  fstream file;


  public:
  int getNumSongs();
  int getMemoryUsage();
  int addSong(string, string, int);
  int deleteSong(string);
  int shuffle();
  int clearSongList();
  int showSongList();
  int sortSongList();
  int getTotalMemory();
  int getRemainingMemory();

  //constructor
  tsuPod(int, int);


};
```

And so you can see, here is my test_tsuPod.cpp which is the driver for this program

```
#include <iostream> // here is line # 9, as compiler says something about this line
#include "tsuPod.h"
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const int MAX_SONGS = 25;
  const int MAX_MEMORY = 100;



  tsuPod TsuPodApp = tsuPod(MAX_SONGS, MAX_MEMORY);

  cout << "Total memory : " << TsuPodApp.getTotalMemory() << endl;

  TsuPodApp.addSong("Something", "artist", 80);
  TsuPodApp.addSong("2", "artist num 2", 10);

  cout << "Remaining Memory : " << TsuPodApp.getRemainingMemory() << endl;

  TsuPodApp.addSong("3", "artist num 3", 1);
  TsuPodApp.addSong("4", "artist num 4", 1);
  TsuPodApp.addSong("5", "Other artist", 10); // should trigger memory error


  TsuPodApp.showSongList();

  TsuPodApp.deleteSong("2");

  TsuPodApp.showSongList();

  cout << "Remaining Memory : " << TsuPodApp.getRemainingMemory() << endl;

  TsuPodApp.sortSongList();

  TsuPodApp.showSongList();

  TsuPodApp.clearSongList();

  TsuPodApp.showSongList();


  return 0;
}
```

Awesome! It seems you guys fixed the cop constructor error I was having! But now when I try to compile I get this message - , which is weird because I'm positive those functions are defined. Any ideas?

```
/tmp/ccu7S45x.o: In function `tsuPod::addSong(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)':
tsuPod.cpp:(.text+0x20d): undefined reference to `Song::Song(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'
tsuPod.cpp:(.text+0x28d): undefined reference to `Song::getTitle()'
tsuPod.cpp:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `Song::getArtist()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Alright, as requested here is Song.cpp - man this is a long post haha

```
#include "Song.h"



string Song::getTitle()
{
  return title;
}

string Song::getArtist()
{
  return artist;
}

int Song::getSize()
{
  return size;
}

int Song::setTitle(string some)
{
  if(some.length() == 0)
  {
    cout << "To add a song, it has to have a title."
    << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  title = some;
  return 1;
}

int Song::setArtist(string some)
{
  if(some.length() == 0)
  {
    cout << "To add a song, it has to have an artist name."
    << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  artist = some;
  return 1;
}

int Song::setSize(int some)
{
  if(some <= 0)
  {
    cout << "To add a song, it has to have minimum size of 1 mb." << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  size = some;
  return 1;
}

Song::Song(string song_title, string song_artist, int song_size)
{
  if(song_title.length() == 0 || song_artist.length() == 0)
  {
    cout << "To add a song, it has to have a name and artist name."
    << endl;
    return;
  }
  if(song_size <= 0)
  {
    cout << "To add a song, it has to have minimum size of 1 mb." << endl;
    return;
  }
  title  = song_title;
  artist = song_artist;
  size   = song_size;
}
```

And song.h below

```
#ifndef __project5__Song__
#define __project5__Song__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#endif /* defined(__project5__Song__) */


class Song {
  private:
    string title;
    string artist;
    int size;
  public:
    string getTitle();
    string getArtist();
    int getSize();
    int setTitle(string);
    int setArtist(string);
    int setSize(int);

  // constructor
  Song(string, string, int);

};
```

Comment: You could show tsuPod.h and the test files for starter.

Comment: Nor should you include `Song.h` in the list of files to compile. Assuming you have something like `#include "Song.h"`, then the compiler will literally copy/paste the contents of the file `Song.h` at that point in your source file. You don't need to tell it to compile the file again.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to copy or return an `fstream`, which isn't supported even in the latest trunk version of gcc.

Comment: @user657267 Well, copying _any_ kind of stream doesn't actually even make any sense.

Comment: @SchighSchagh no but they're at least movable in C++11, but gcc hasn't got around to implementing it yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not copying or returning an fstream anywhere, I think I saw that somewhere else on here so I double checked. I'll try compiling everything but song.h

Comment: You are trying to copy the stream somewhere. But we need to see your code in order to find out *where*.

Comment: Okay, I added my driver and tsuPod.h --- I will add more, but it's just a lot of code so I didn't know how much and what all you wanted me to upload. Thanks you guys so much!

Comment: @0x499602D2 when you say I'm trying to copy a stream... maybe I misunderstood what that means. Can you clarify? I might be able to identify it in the rest of my code (which is a lot) if I know what exactly to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is trying to emit an implicit copy constructor for `tsuPod`, which it cannot do because the `fstream` member is uncopyable. You are trying to copy your class at `test_tsuPod.cpp:23`.

Comment: That actually helped quite a bit! The error message is much shorter now, and it's a different error message as well... Would you be kind enough to look at that error as well and maybe help me out a little?

Comment: See the other answer.

Comment: Got it! But now I'm getting another error, I updated at bottom of question.

Comment: You'll need to post `Song.cpp`, it looks like you're missing some definitions. Also you don't need to specify the `.h` files when compiling.

Comment: err might need `Song.h` too.

Comment: Got it! Anything else?

Comment: Just to make sure, calling `g++ Song.cpp test_tsuPod.cpp tsuPod.cpp` gives the same error?

Answer (score 1):

The line causing the problem is this one:

```c++
tsuPod TsuPodApp = tsuPod(MAX_SONGS, MAX_MEMORY);
```

This line is constructing `TsuPodApp` from a temporary value. When this happens, the compiler will try to copy the temporary into `TsuPodApp`. But in order for that to happen the class `tsuPod` must have a copy-constructor. Because `std::fstream` has a private copy-constructor (deleted in C++11) the class cannot be copied, hence the error.

The solution is to construct `TsuPodApp` directly, like this:

```c++
tsuPod TsuPodApp(MAX_SONGS, MAX_MEMORY);
```

The only constructor that will be called here is the constructor that you defined (`tsuPod(int, int)`).

Comment: Got it! But now I'm getting another error, I updated at bottom of question.

Answer (score 1):

change:

`tsuPod TsuPodApp = tsuPod(MAX_SONGS, MAX_MEMORY);`

to:

`tsuPod TsuPodApp(MAX_SONGS, MAX_MEMORY);`

g++ a.cc a.h -o a.o

g++ b.cc b.h a.o -o myexe

etc..

Comment: Got it! But now I'm getting another error, I updated at bottom of question.

Comment: try separate the compilation in 2 lines

Comment: im confused what you mean by a.cc and a.o etc.. Are these generic filenames?